# MvcMiniProfiler results/chicklets are hidden/covered by a DIV

Tags: html, css, mvc-mini-profiler

Any way to control the display properties of MvcMiniProfiler?  I actually have a DIV banner (stole look and idea from the SO banner that shows - i.e. 'Congrats, you've gained the privilege...') that displays at the top of the browser at all times.

When this message/DIV is displayed it covers up 1-2 chicklets and I have no way of expanding them to see profiling information.

Any ideas?

Update: Here is my CSS for the div/message.  I think I stole SO directly, but did it long ago so maybe they changed.

```
#altDBToolbar 
{ 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3b5998; 
    background: #6d84b4; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    z-index: 1000; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
#altDBToolbar p
{
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean by chicklets? O_o

Comment: Please update your question with the CSS for the div. I suspect you use a display:absolute or fixed for it.

Comment: Hmm...chicklets...thought I heard that term thrown around for the little notification areas in upper left that contain clickable region to show the profiling information :)  Maybe I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving 
.profiler-results a z-index > 1000